# How to easilly see number of event subscriptions while debugging?

Tags: c#, events, subscription, eventtrigger

While debugging, can I look into `textBox1.TextChanged` to see the number of event subscriptions? If yes, then how do I drill to it? I need to know how many subscriptions there are at a given time for debugging because it looks like an event is triggered multiple times, but I suspect this bug is really because `textBox1.TextChanged += handler` is being mismanaged in the application, so there are too many subscribers.

Here is a simplified version of what I think is happening. If possible, I just want to set a breakpoint and count up the number of subscriptions to "textBox1.TextChanged":

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    MessageBox.Show("asdf");
    textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;        
    textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
}
```

Is that possible or is it more complicated?

Comment: Why downvoting? It's a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use Reflection to get to the invocation list of the event delegate:

```
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    MessageBox.Show("asdf");
    textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;        
    textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    var eventField = textBox1.GetType().GetField("TextChanged", BindingFlags.GetField
                                                               | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                               | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var subscriberCount = ((EventHandler)eventField.GetValue(textBox1))
                .GetInvocationList().Length;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're only concerned with doing it under the debugger, rather than programmatically, then this is perhaps a simpler, non-invasive way:

```
class _24003458
{
    event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public void Test()
    {
        MyEvent += Handler1;
        MyEvent += Handler2;
        MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    void Handler1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    void Handler2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Put a breakpoint on either of the event handlers, and when it breaks, look at the Locals tab. The event, when expanded, will show the invocation count and event handlers:

[image: Screenshot of program stopped at breakpoint and Locals window showing the expanded event with invocation count and handlers]

Comment: Awesome response. Could I do something similar to find a ComboBox's TextChanged event (i.e., via Locals)? I looked around for a while but couldn't find the ComboBox's events when drilling. This will be helpful nonetheless, so thanks.

Comment: If you can navigate from `this` to your ComboBox, you'll be able to get from there to its events.

Comment: In VS 2017, this event field is hidden in debugger. Looks like VS debugger changed the event visibility engine in Locals tab

Comment: When I put `this.FormClosing` into the watch window, I get error CS0079: The event 'Form.FormClosing' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: @ThomasWeller Indeed, which is why I started from `this` and drilled down.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>It is not possible with an event like this (for good reason), however,</strike>  it is possable via reflection as [Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22) says, [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24003912/442351)) if you are using an event directly you can do so:

```
private event EventHandler handler;

var delegates = handler.GetInvocationList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a member method which you add to the object which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. It makes debugging very easy:

```
#if DEBUG
    public System.Delegate[] GetInvocationList()
    {
        return PropertyChanged?.GetInvocationList();
    }
#endif
```